# Can we define context variables in a flat file and then use them in the job?

Tags: talend

I am trying to create a module that will look for files and if present archive to a new location. I want filename and path to be given at run time as i am planning to use this module across many jobs. Is there a way where we can define the context variables in a file and then use that file in multiple jobs with different values ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define context variables in a file and you can give its path in your job. We call it parameter files and they *normally* have an extension of **.properties**.They contain key value pair of you context variables and their values.

For example,

`date=20-Nov-2017
time=12:47`

In above example, date and time are the context variables.

The process of loading a parameter file can be implemented in different ways. Below is the method which I use.

To load the file in beginning of your job, you will have to make a sub-job using components **tFileInputProperties** and **tContextLoad**. You will have to define schema also. In tFileInputProperties takes the path of you parameter file. Then you can link this sub-job with your main job using **OnSubjobOk**. Make a subjob like this and change the path of the parameter file in tFileInputProperties in every job. It will load all the context variables before running your actual job.

A different logic is given in [here](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-load-context-example.html). You can follow this logic also.